# How to reset WinHTTP proxy credentials after a failed request?

Tags: windows, winapi, winhttp

I need to write code to download a file and the requirements are as follows.  If the application is configured to use a proxy, attempt to download via the proxy.  If that fails, attempt a direct connection.  If no proxy is configured, attempt a direct connection.  High-level pseudo-code:

```
if(ProxyEnabled)
    if(!DownloadWithProxy())
        DownloadWithoutProxy()
else
    DownloadWithoutProxy()
```

I'm using WinHTTP since this code will be running in a service.  The actual downloading is straightforward but I'm having issues with the proxy settings.  My current pseudo-code is as follows:

```
hSession = WinHttpOpen(..., WINHTTP_ACCESS_TYPE_DEFAULT_PROXY, ...)
hConnect = WinHttpConnect(hSession, ...)
hRequest = WinHttpOpenRequest(hConnect, ...)
if(Proxy.Enabled)
{
    // set proxy server
    WinHttpSetOption(hRequest, WINHTTP_OPTION_PROXY, ServerName)
    // set proxy credentials
    WinHttpSetCredentials(hRequest, WINHTTP_AUTH_TARGET_PROXY, UserName, Password)
    if(!DownloadFile(hRequest))
    {
        // reset proxy server
        WinHttpSetOption(hRequest, WINHTTP_OPTION_PROXY, NULL)
        // reset proxy credentials
        WinHttpSetCredentials(hRequest, WINHTTP_AUTH_TARGET_PROXY, NULL, NULL)
        DownloadFile(hRequest)
    }
}
else
{
    DownloadFile(hRequest)
}
```

Where `DownloadFile()` does the standard `WinHttpSendRequest()` and `WinHttpReceiveResponse()` sequence.  Everything works fine except in the case where the download via the proxy fails.  When that happens the call to `WinHttpSetCredentials()` to reset the credentials fails (with ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER), and as a result the second call to `DownloadFile()` still tries to use the proxy (even though I reset it) and the credentials.  NOTE: In this specific scenario I am using a valid proxy server but invalid proxy credentials to trigger the failure.

So I guess my question is what is the best approach?  As far as I can tell it is not possible to reset the credentials set via `WinHttpSetCredentials()`, so I guess I should just recreate the request for each call to `DownloadFile()` rather than trying to be "clever" by reusing a single request object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WinHttpSetCredentials()` takes 6 parameters, one of which is the auth scheme.  You have only shown 4 parameters, and do not say which auth scheme you are using.  Overall, your sequence for authenticating is different than what MSDN suggests:

[Authentication in WinHTTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383144.aspx)

> A typical WinHTTP application completes the following steps in order to handle authentication.
>
> •Request a resource with WinHttpOpenRequest and WinHttpSendRequest.
>   •Check the response headers with WinHttpQueryHeaders.
>   •If a 401 or 407 status code is returned indicating that authentication is required, call WinHttpQueryAuthSchemes to find an acceptable scheme.
>   •Set the authentication scheme, username, and password with WinHttpSetCredentials.
>   •Resend the request with the same request handle by calling WinHttpSendRequest.

Also take note of this condition:

> **The credentials set by WinHttpSetCredentials are only used for one request.** WinHTTP does not cache the credentials to use in other requests, which means that applications must be written that can respond to multiple requests. If an authenticated connection is re-used, other requests may not be challenged, but your code should be able to respond to a request at any time.

The documentation linked above includes the following code example for how to use `WinHTTPSetCredentials()` correctly:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <winhttp.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "winhttp.lib")

DWORD ChooseAuthScheme( DWORD dwSupportedSchemes )
{
  //  It is the server's responsibility only to accept 
  //  authentication schemes that provide a sufficient
  //  level of security to protect the servers resources.
  //
  //  The client is also obligated only to use an authentication
  //  scheme that adequately protects its username and password.
  //
  //  Thus, this sample code does not use Basic authentication  
  //  becaus Basic authentication exposes the client's username
  //  and password to anyone monitoring the connection.

  if( dwSupportedSchemes & WINHTTP_AUTH_SCHEME_NEGOTIATE )
    return WINHTTP_AUTH_SCHEME_NEGOTIATE;
  else if( dwSupportedSchemes & WINHTTP_AUTH_SCHEME_NTLM )
    return WINHTTP_AUTH_SCHEME_NTLM;
  else if( dwSupportedSchemes & WINHTTP_AUTH_SCHEME_PASSPORT )
    return WINHTTP_AUTH_SCHEME_PASSPORT;
  else if( dwSupportedSchemes & WINHTTP_AUTH_SCHEME_DIGEST )
    return WINHTTP_AUTH_SCHEME_DIGEST;
  else
    return 0;
}

struct SWinHttpSampleGet
{
  LPCWSTR szServer;
  LPCWSTR szPath;
  BOOL fUseSSL;
  LPCWSTR szServerUsername;
  LPCWSTR szServerPassword;
  LPCWSTR szProxyUsername;
  LPCWSTR szProxyPassword;
};

void WinHttpAuthSample( IN SWinHttpSampleGet *pGetRequest )
{
  DWORD dwStatusCode = 0;
  DWORD dwSupportedSchemes;
  DWORD dwFirstScheme;
  DWORD dwSelectedScheme;
  DWORD dwTarget;
  DWORD dwLastStatus = 0;
  DWORD dwSize = sizeof(DWORD);
  BOOL  bResults = FALSE;
  BOOL  bDone = FALSE;

  DWORD dwProxyAuthScheme = 0;
  HINTERNET  hSession = NULL, 
             hConnect = NULL,
             hRequest = NULL;

  // Use WinHttpOpen to obtain a session handle.
  hSession = WinHttpOpen( L"WinHTTP Example/1.0",  
                          WINHTTP_ACCESS_TYPE_DEFAULT_PROXY,
                          WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_NAME, 
                          WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_BYPASS, 0 );

  INTERNET_PORT nPort = ( pGetRequest->fUseSSL ) ? 
                        INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTPS_PORT  :
                        INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT;

  // Specify an HTTP server.
  if( hSession )
    hConnect = WinHttpConnect( hSession, 
                               pGetRequest->szServer, 
                               nPort, 0 );

  // Create an HTTP request handle.
  if( hConnect )
    hRequest = WinHttpOpenRequest( hConnect, 
                                   L"GET", 
                                   pGetRequest->szPath,
                                   NULL, 
                                   WINHTTP_NO_REFERER, 
                                   WINHTTP_DEFAULT_ACCEPT_TYPES,
                                   ( pGetRequest->fUseSSL ) ? 
                                       WINHTTP_FLAG_SECURE : 0 );

  // Continue to send a request until status code 
  // is not 401 or 407.
  if( hRequest == NULL )
    bDone = TRUE;

  while( !bDone )
  {
    //  If a proxy authentication challenge was responded to, reset
    //  those credentials before each SendRequest, because the proxy  
    //  may require re-authentication after responding to a 401 or  
    //  to a redirect. If you don't, you can get into a 
    //  407-401-407-401- loop.
    if( dwProxyAuthScheme != 0 )
      bResults = WinHttpSetCredentials( hRequest, 
                                        WINHTTP_AUTH_TARGET_PROXY, 
                                        dwProxyAuthScheme, 
                                        pGetRequest->szProxyUsername,
                                        pGetRequest->szProxyPassword,
                                        NULL );
    // Send a request.
    bResults = WinHttpSendRequest( hRequest,
                                   WINHTTP_NO_ADDITIONAL_HEADERS,
                                   0,
                                   WINHTTP_NO_REQUEST_DATA,
                                   0, 
                                   0, 
                                   0 );

    // End the request.
    if( bResults )
      bResults = WinHttpReceiveResponse( hRequest, NULL );

    // Resend the request in case of 
    // ERROR_WINHTTP_RESEND_REQUEST error.
    if( !bResults && GetLastError( ) == ERROR_WINHTTP_RESEND_REQUEST)
        continue;

    // Check the status code.
    if( bResults ) 
      bResults = WinHttpQueryHeaders( hRequest, 
                                      WINHTTP_QUERY_STATUS_CODE |
                                      WINHTTP_QUERY_FLAG_NUMBER,
                                      NULL, 
                                      &dwStatusCode, 
                                      &dwSize, 
                                      NULL );

    if( bResults )
    {
      switch( dwStatusCode )
      {
        case 200: 
          // The resource was successfully retrieved.
          // You can use WinHttpReadData to read the 
          // contents of the server's response.
          printf( "The resource was successfully retrieved.\n" );
          bDone = TRUE;
          break;

        case 401:
          // The server requires authentication.
          printf(" The server requires authentication. Sending credentials...\n" );

          // Obtain the supported and preferred schemes.
          bResults = WinHttpQueryAuthSchemes( hRequest, 
                                              &dwSupportedSchemes, 
                                              &dwFirstScheme, 
                                              &dwTarget );

          // Set the credentials before resending the request.
          if( bResults )
          {
            dwSelectedScheme = ChooseAuthScheme( dwSupportedSchemes);

            if( dwSelectedScheme == 0 )
              bDone = TRUE;
            else
              bResults = WinHttpSetCredentials( hRequest, 
                                        dwTarget, 
                                        dwSelectedScheme,
                                        pGetRequest->szServerUsername,
                                        pGetRequest->szServerPassword,
                                        NULL );
          }

          // If the same credentials are requested twice, abort the
          // request.  For simplicity, this sample does not check
          // for a repeated sequence of status codes.
          if( dwLastStatus == 401 )
            bDone = TRUE;

          break;

        case 407:
          // The proxy requires authentication.
          printf( "The proxy requires authentication.  Sending credentials...\n" );

          // Obtain the supported and preferred schemes.
          bResults = WinHttpQueryAuthSchemes( hRequest, 
                                              &dwSupportedSchemes, 
                                              &dwFirstScheme, 
                                              &dwTarget );

          // Set the credentials before resending the request.
          if( bResults )
            dwProxyAuthScheme = ChooseAuthScheme(dwSupportedSchemes);

          // If the same credentials are requested twice, abort the
          // request.  For simplicity, this sample does not check 
          // for a repeated sequence of status codes.
          if( dwLastStatus == 407 )
            bDone = TRUE;
          break;

        default:
          // The status code does not indicate success.
          printf("Error. Status code %d returned.\n", dwStatusCode);
          bDone = TRUE;
      }
    }

    // Keep track of the last status code.
    dwLastStatus = dwStatusCode;

    // If there are any errors, break out of the loop.
    if( !bResults ) 
        bDone = TRUE;
  }

  // Report any errors.
  if( !bResults )
  {
    DWORD dwLastError = GetLastError( );
    printf( "Error %d has occurred.\n", dwLastError );
  }

  // Close any open handles.
  if( hRequest ) WinHttpCloseHandle( hRequest );
  if( hConnect ) WinHttpCloseHandle( hConnect );
  if( hSession ) WinHttpCloseHandle( hSession );
}
```

You just have to inject your `WinHttpSetOption(WINHTTP_OPTION_PROXY)` where appropriate, and be sure that you are handling authentication requests for both proxy and non-proxy connections (in case the target HTTP server requires its own authentication).

Comment: I'm not sure if this is documented anywhere, but the behavior I observed (via Wireshark) is that if you call `WinHttpSetCredentials()` prior to the first `WinHttpSendRequest()` call then the 407 status code is handled transparently (assuming valid credentials, obviously) so there's no need to handle it explicitly (at least for my scenario).  In any event, I couldn't figure out how to clear the credentials once they had been set so I just gave up and took the less "clever" approach of creating a new request object.  I'll accept your answer for making the effort.

Comment: It is documented, by the same "Authentication in WinHTTP" page that my answer links to: "If an acceptable authentication scheme and credentials are known before a request is sent to the server, an application can call WinHttpSetCredentials before calling WinHttpSendRequest. In this case, WinHTTP attempts pre-authentication with the server by providing credentials or authentication data in the initial request to the server. Pre-authentication can decrease the number of exchanges in the authentication process and therefore improve application performance."